# open() function in C to creat new file with wrong permission?

Tags: c

I tried to create new file with rwx permission for Others user bellow:

```
int fd = open (myfile, O_CREAT, S_IRWXO);
```

but when I check, "myfile" only have r-x permission for Others user.
I use Ubuntu 12.0.

What issue occurred?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what happens when oring with `S_IRWXU` ?

Comment: Anything to do with current linux user umask ?

Comment: I will try with umask and give you the result. Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the default value of `umask` is `022`, so when a new file is created, the write permission is automatically removed.
For fix your problem, remove the umask (or reconfigure it) :

```
$ umask 000
```

or in your programm with the umask() function

```
mode_t umask(mode_t mask);
umask(0)
```

But care, give write and execution privilege to everyone can be dangerous

Comment: The diagnosis is correct, but setting `umask` to zero isn’t good security.  You seldom want others to write to your files, especially not executable files.  It’s weird to deny group access while permitting others; ditto for the user/owner, except the owner can change permissions whereas group can’t.